# Error converting IplImage** to IplImage*

Tags: image, opencv, iplimage

```
IplImage *img;
img = (IplImage **)malloc(IMAGE_NUM * sizeof(IplImage *));

for(index=0; index<IMAGE_NUM; index++){
    sprintf(filename, "preproc/preproc%d.jpg", index);
    img = cvLoadImage(filename, 0);
}
```

Hi! This piece of code here produces the error: cannot convert ‘IplImage** {aka _IplImage**}’ to ‘IplImage* {aka _IplImage*}’ in assignment. I am trying to load multiple images here. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declare 'img' to be a pointer to IplImage and then you're trying to convert it into pointer to a pointer. `(IplImage**)` - This typecast is incorrect for this particular case since you're trying to assign IplImage** to a IplImage*.

Declare img to be : IplImage **img;

Comment: If img is declared as IplImage **img, then how can I access its width and height? And how can I correctly use functions as cvSetImageROI? What is the correct syntax because I am having problems with them after declaring img as above. Thank you very much!

Comment: Think of it like this : If we declare a pointer to an object, or an arbitrary data-type, say int* pointerToInt; we can make this pointer to point to (simply put) an array of integers. If we do so (either statically or dynamically), we can then access Nth member of our array by saying : pointerToInt[N]. Notice that even if we declare our array dynamically (int* pointerToInt = new int[MagicalNumber]) and therefore really stating that we have a pointer, we can still access it via array subscript operator []. So pointerToInt[MagicalNumber-1] works. Same applies for 2D arrays.

Comment: We have int** pointerToIntPointer - This declares a pointer to a pointer. Dynamically allocating this would involve a loop and i don't want to go into details here but again, we can statically say : int pointerToIntPointer[MagicalNumber0][MagicalNumber1]; and then access the array with array subscript operator - int pointerToIntPointer[MagicalNumber0-1][MagicalNumber1-1]; We could do the same syntax for a dynamically allocated array which resembles ' a raw pointer ' a little bit more. Also never forget to delete[] the arrays you dynamically allocate! :) Just sayin'.

Comment: Sorry for the possible confusion by the way, new is the c++'s version of malloc while delete is it's evil twin free. Breaking the habit could be difficult. (This subject leads further to ' pointer aritmethics ' if you're interested in how the array subscript works.)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
IplImage** img;
img = (IplImage**)malloc(IMAGE_NUM * sizeof(IplImage *));

for(index=0; index<IMAGE_NUM; index++){
    sprintf(filename, "preproc/preproc%d.jpg", index);
    *img = cvLoadImage(filename, 0);
}
```

by the way, the next error you'll get will be for not advancing the img pointer after each loop iteration

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring `IplImage** img;`, then `img[index] = cvLoadImage(filename, 0)`, since `img` is an array of IplImage pointers and cvLoadImage() returns a single image.